# How to Show Images from Storage Path using Livewire in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, image, storage, laravel-livewire

[image]I am new in using Livewire for my cart in my e-commerce Laravel 7 project. I want to show the product image of each item in the cart. I have `@foreach ($cartItems as $item)` on my table data. When I try this code

`<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$item->cover_img)}}">`

to try to show the images saved to my storage path, I get an error like the image above. But when I try:

`<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$item['cover_img'])}}">`

I'm getting an `ErrorException Undefined index: cover_img`. All the other $item is working and getting the needed data except the image. On my other blades without livewire `<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$item->cover_img)}}>` works fine.

How do I do this properly in livewire? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

When I do a `{{dd($item)}}`, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to apply the same 'arrow' syntax in your liveware file too? So instead of `$item['cover_img']` write `$item->cover_img`. Can you somehow get the output of how `$item` looks like in your Livewire blade?

Comment: can you check `dump(is_object($item))` and tell if it returns true or false

Comment: I'm getting a different error `ErrorException
Trying to get property 'cover_img' of non-object ` upon trying `dump(is_object($item))`. When I try to do `{{dd($item)}}`, I can get an array of collection including cover-img.

Comment: Its an array, not an object. So `<img src="{{ asset($image['associatedModel']['cover_img']) }} " />`?

Comment: Thank you for all your advices and help. I was able to make it work using `<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item['associatedModel']['cover_img']) }} " />`. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item['associatedModel']['cover_img']) }} " />
```

Thanks!